# Assigning pointer member of a struct to null

Tags: c, pointers

I am having some difficulty assigning a pointer inside a struct to null. Since pointers are pass by value, I can't find an easy way to do this. Maybe its been a long day and I can''t think straight. Anyways, here is my code:

```
void
init_wordrec (wordrec *rec)
{
    if ((rec = (wordrec *) malloc(sizeof(wordrec))) == NULL) {
        perror("Malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    rec->word = NULL;
    rec->hits = 0;
    rec->nxt_wd = NULL;
}
```

Here is the `wordrec` struct:

```
typedef struct wordrec
{
    char *word;
    int hits;
    struct wordrec *nxt_wd;
} wordrec;
```

I want the actual word pointer to point to null, unfortunately my attempts have only caused gcc to complain loudly.

EDIT: Here is a method where I pass in word struct.

```
void
add_word (char *word, wordrec *head)
{
    wordrec *iter = head;
    wordrec *tmp;
    if (iter->word == NULL) { //This should be NULL but is not
        if ((iter->word = (char *) malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
            perror("Malloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        strncpy(iter->word, word, strlen(word) + 1);
        iter->hits++;
        init_wordrec (iter->nxt_wd);
    } else if (strcmp(iter->word, word) < 0) {
        init_wordrec (tmp);
        if ((tmp->word = (char *) malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
            perror("Malloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        strncpy(tmp->word, word, strlen(word) + 1);
        tmp->hits++;
        tmp->nxt_wd = head; 
        head = tmp;
    } else if (strcmp(iter->word, word) > 0) {
        add_word (word, iter->nxt_wd);
    } else {
        iter->hits++;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int 
main()
{
    wordrec head;
    char word1[] = "Hello";
    init_wordrec (&head);
    add_word(word1, &head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Did you `#include <stdio.h>` or other?

Comment: I added additional code to provide more context. I get a segfault but through gdb, it is because the conditional testing for null (in the comments) failed.

Comment: If u do ` wordrec head;
    char word1[] = "Hello";
    init_wordrec (&head);` then malloc should not be used in init_wordrec as it creates another copy of this struct which is then initialzied. The one which you passed as argument is not changed then.

Comment: `strncpy(tmp->word, word, strlen(word) + 1);` is the same as `strcpy(tmp->word, word);` (in terms of the string being copied).  It's good to avoid the unsafe function `strncpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment goes the other way — you assign a value, such as `NULL`, to a variable, such as `rec->word`.

You could pass a double pointer to the function:

```
void
init_wordrec (wordrec **rec)
{
    if ((*rec = (wordrec *) malloc(sizeof(wordrec))) == NULL) {
        perror("Malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    (*rec)->word = NULL;
    (*rec)->hits = 0;
    (*rec)->nxt_wd = NULL;
}
/* ... */
wordrec *wr = 0;
init_wordrec(&wr);
```

but since you're allocating in the function (so you're just going to throw away the value passed in) making it return the new record usually simplifies the code:

```
wordrec*
init_wordrec(void)
{
    wordrec *rec = malloc(sizeof(*rec));
    if (rec == NULL) {
        perror("Malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    rec->word = NULL;
    rec->hits = 0;
    rec->nxt_wd = NULL;
    return rec;
}
/* ... */
wordrec *wr = init_wordrec();
```

You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`; it will make the code compile even if you fail to include its prototype, but will fail badly at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean something like this:

```
void init_wordrec(wordrec **rec)
{
    if ((*rec = (wordrec *) malloc(sizeof(wordrec))) == NULL) {
        perror("Malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    (*rec)->word = NULL;
    (*rec)->hits = 0;
    (*rec)->nxt_wd = NULL;
}
....
wordrec *wr;
init_wordrec(&wr);
```

Comment: Oh I see, I need to pass in the actual struct.

Comment: Just to unpack that a bit, you have to do `**rec` because init_wordrec() is itself mallocing a pointer, which returns an entirely different memory address.  You can modify what is at the memory location a pointer points to when you pass it in, but you cannot  change the memory location the pointer points to when you pass it in.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option would be:

```
void init_wordrec (wordrec *rec)
{
    rec->word = NULL;
    rec->hits = 0;
    rec->nxt_wd = NULL;
}
```

which allows your code in `main` to remain unchanged:

```
int main()
{
    wordrec head;
    char word1[] = "Hello";
    init_wordrec (&head);
```

Another advantage of this is that users of `wordrec` have the option to use automatic allocation or dynamic allocation (whereas the other proposed answers force dynamic allocation to be used).